# How to Use Regex to Replace All Occurrences of "\ctft{*}" into "\application{\ctftop}{*}"

Tags: editors

In my document, I defined a macro `\newcommand{\ctft}[1]{\mathscr{F}#1}` for applying continuous time Fourier transform. An example in my code that uses the ctft command is `\ctft{\delta_{a}}`. Later on, for generality, I created a new macro `\newcommand{\application}[2]{{#1}{#2}}` to represent the idea of applying a function and a new macro `\newcommand{\ctftop}{\mathscr{F}}` to represent the operator for continuous time Fourier transform. So now, I would like to change all forms of `\ctft{something}` into `\application{\ctftop}{something}`. I tried making this modification using the regex `\\ctft\{(.*?)\}`, but failed: this regex would capture `\ctft{\delta_{a}`, instead of `\ctft{\delta_{a}}`. So it seems that the regex has to be able to ensure equal numbers for delimiters `{` and `}`. How can I make this happen using regex?

Comment: That's a question about the editor, rather than TeX.

Comment: you can not mach arbitrary nested braces with a regex (that's essentially what the "regular" in "regular expression" means) but why do you ned a regex, don't you just want to change `\ctft{` to `\application{\cftop}{` ?

Comment: your `\application` macro seems wrong, `\application{\sin}{x}`  would produce `{\sin}{x}`not `\sin {x}`  so would lose the operator spacing for `\sin`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - If we're talking about balanced nested braces, you can try putting `\ctft{\delta_{a}}` in a .tex file, do `M-x re-builder` in your favorite editor and yank this snippet for the regexp string: `\\\\ctft{\\([^}{]*\\({[^}{]*}[^}{]*\\)*[^}]*\\)}`.  Things get complicated once you have escaped braces.

Comment: @ArashEsbati you can match braces to any fixed depth, that one if I read it right matches `{}` containing possible `{}` groups that don't contain braces. but regex can not count (some systems provide non-regular extensions that can match braces) so you can not match `{{{{a}b}c}}` with the one you show.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Yes, the one I showed only works for one level of braces inside the mandatory arg.  One could go further with something like this `\\\\ctft{\\([^}{]*\\({[^}{]*\\({[^}{]*\\({[^}{]*}[^}{]*\\)*}[^}{]*\\)*}[^}{]*\\)*\\)}` to match more levels (3 in this case).  In general, you're right, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a regex here, just replace `\ctft{` by `\application{\cftop}{`

Comment: My bad... I only thought of using a general tool, but didn't think of this simple solution :)